# Executing sed program in Windows 7's command line generates "sedXXXX" files

Tags: windows, sed, command-prompt

I work on Windows 7 and I execute the sed program in command line to edit configuration files. It works great, but as a result of a successful execution, a "sedXXX" (for exmple "sedujYHiL") file is always generated in the directory containing the edited file. I don't want such a file be generated.

The command I use is:

```
C:/sed/bin/sed.exe -i -c "sIP_DB#10.90.80.192#g" C:/standalone-full-ha.xml
```

To find a solution I have executed:

```
C:/sed/bin/sed.exe --help
```

then I have tried to modify my command to meet my need (I notably have tried to remove the "-c" argument), but without meeting success: a "sedXXX" file is always generated.

What can I do?
Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely to be a temporary file and the version of sed isn't deleting them.

Try a different port of SED, maybe GNUsed.

Your sed command looks to be faulty, also.